# Changing sign-in name in AAD B2C

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, identity, policy

I'm trying to implement [Change Sign-in Name flow](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/change-sign-in-name) from AAD B2C samples. Basically the policy works but the problem is that the user is still logged in after changing his e-mail.

In my understanding changing the primary identity must invalidate all issued tokens/sessions immediately and force the user to re-authenticate. How come this can be secure and isn't addressed in the sample? How can I do it? I could redirect the request to the B2C sign-out endpoint but here is another issue:

When a user clicks "Change Sign-In Name" link he gets redirected to the policy endpoint with a specified `redirect_uri` query string param. In my case it's `https://localhost:44300`. The problem is he gets redirected back to my site when he finishes the flow **and** when he cancels the flow and I cannot distinguish between the two as there seems to be nothing in the request to check.

So, how can I get the user back to `https://localhost:44300` if he cancels the flow (the email isn't changed) and perform Single Sign-Out if he finishes the flow?

Answer (score 2):

Why should changing a username invalidate the session? I can only agree with password change. B2C has no understanding of what is happening (except for password changes) it simply does what you’ve asked. All journeys issue a token at the end, you can put a self asserted page and disable the continue button, then use JavaScript to send the user to the app’s logout route if this is what you want.

In the successful policy execution, you get a token back with the unique policy id.

In a failure you get an error sent to the app. Use this to distinguish between them.

To manage the user cancelling, send an encoded state parameter with the auth request, it’ll be returned with the “cancel error” (AADB2C error user cancelled” to your app, then do the logout. Seems like very poor UX and no security gains.

Comment: After a user changes his UPN we have no guarantee he still owns that UPN. Thus, all tokens issued so far cannot be trusted anymore. The lookups to external systems might either fail or return data of another person.

Comment: Thanks for the state parameter idea, I missed it somehow!

Comment: If you have the user verify the new email during the change sign in band journey, which you can and should, I don’t see the issue. The user will get a token with the new signInName after the journey completes. Status quo.

Comment: Yes, but the old tokens with the old email are still valid, aren't they?

Comment: Yes they are. Forcing a logout on one device is not going to change that though. In fact nothing you can do will invalidate id/access tokens. Only the B2C SSO web session cookies are destroyed on the local machine by forcing a logout. Refresh tokens can be invalidated but it doesn’t achieve much again in this case, people don’t change sign in name for that.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very good question. When the token is generated it has a lifespan of a set time. For example 1 hour.

When you use this token, it is assumed that the user is good-to-go until the token expires and a refresh token is issued.

When the refresh token is consumed is when a new validation will occur and will need to re-authenticate.